# How to apply static class in php

Tags: java, php

I am java and php programmer.
In java i can use static class/method so that anyone can use the same one time created class during run-time.

But for php how to do it since it is script based and only run while we refreshing the page?

My main objective is, I want to use syncronized class/method so that it wont clash while executing the PHP...

Need your help to give input. 
Thanks

**Update:**

1. I am doing portal like multi level marketing(mlm)
2. Once register a member, we should pay bonus to the uplines
3. I don't want immidiately calculate the bonus because it is risky and could take some time to finish, so is is better just to register the member and show successfull.
4. My idea is, after registration, just invoke another class to run bonus with syncronized method so that the bonus calculation will not disturb by another registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that a php scripts runs from new every sinlge  time a "static" class would not be very different from an ordinary class.

If you want to store some sort of state or preserve some data between runs of a php program then there are a number of options.

SESSION variables can be used to store data between requests from a single users as long as he keeps the session open.

COOKIES can be used to store data which persists between sessions as long as the user is using the same browser, on hte same machine and hasnt emptied the cookie jar.

memchached and similar packages can be used to store data and make it available to any php program on the server.

Databases are the most scalable solution as they will persist data between sessions, and between servers. There is some overhead involved is establishing connections and retrieving the data compared with the other solutions.

Comment: This is good comment... I should choose the database option and run by cron-job every 5 minutes

Answer (score 2):

PHP is shared-nothing. Everything just lives for the Request. If you want to share information between Requests, you have to implement [some](http://de.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php) [additional](http://memcached.org/) [technology](http://gearman.org/) [layer](http://stomp.codehaus.org/) that can do so. Or look into [process control](http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-multi-threading-part-1), [shared memory segments](http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-shared-memory-segments-ipc) and [semaphores](http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-semaphores). The latter three are uncommon usage in PHP though. And all of the above will still be asynchronous.

To my knowledge, there is no way to update class Foo in one Request and have it change state immediately in a concurrent Request with PHP.

Comment: Or better yet, don't use it. It's just *begging* for concurrency problems, and it gets really hard to scale out to multiple servers.

Comment: So.. If we cannot syncronized using php code, i plan to use text file. Put the process in the file and run through cron-job. But the text.txt file writer script(php) is still not syncronized... Anyone experience using simple way because i using shared hosting... cannot install too much in the server.

Comment: @Joe we might be able to help you better if you update your question with more details about what you are really trying to do.

Comment: 1. I am doing portal like multi level marketing(mlm)
2. Once register a member, we should pay bonus to the uplines 
3. I don't want immidiately calculate the bonus because it is risky and could take some time to finish, so is is better just to register the member and show successfull.
4. My idea is, after registration, just invoke another class to run bonus with syncronized method so that the bonus calculation will not disturb by another registration.

Comment: @Joe I dont see how this requires synchronicity

Comment: OK now let say super upline for G is A and super upline for H is also A, super upline for I also is A and so on.... So imagine if there are so many new registration... Of coz we need to sync the bonus aggregation so that the calculation is not missing while there are few registration at the same time...

Comment: Yes you may say that we can just update directly into db statement like "Update tbleX set bonus=bonus+$bonus WHERE id=$id". But the calculation is not just like that.... I need to extract out that current value and do some calculation before commit

Comment: @Joe Cant you just register all the registration and calculate their bonus once a day? I really dont see how this has anything to do with static method calls. Just register all the registrations and then run a Job, either from Cron or a JobQueue once a day to update a user's current bonus level.

Comment: With java, using static to maintain the value so that all request will just get the latest value. But for php i cant see anything such this one. That is for static.
Anyway the syncronization is different thing... it uses for the purpose as i mention above... So there are different thing for me using static and sync

Comment: Anyway, of coz now i am doing the calculation in one day, the cron will look into database for the latest registration and process the bonus based on that for every 5 minutes. So it is only one thread to touch a classes/methods... This solves my sync problem because using only 1 request.
Thanks for helping